# Restricting hibernate's eager fetch beyond DAO

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have my entities as ProductType,Product and ProductInventory.

I have a join query to fetch list of inventory for a specific date range which joins Product and ProductInventory. I've got list of object arrays which I have casted and set it ready.

Now from DAO I return the list of products.

In my layer above, if I execute product.getProductInventory() it is actually firing a query again getting all the inventory and not those inventory as got by the join.

```
    final StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder(
                "from  Product As  rsProduct left outer join rsProduct.inventoryList "
                + "as inventory where rsProduct.efDate <= :travelEndDate AND rsProduct.expDate >= :travelStartDate AND rsProduct.locatiion = :LOCN AND rsProduct.id in (:productsIdList) and inventory.bookDate between :startDate and :endDate");
```

Ex. Say travel start date is 20th Jan and travel end date is 21 Jan. I get only two records here which is perfect.

But after i return to other layer, if i say product.getInventory() it fetches all inventory irrespective of dates.

Can someone address this problem?

Comment: Please format your code. The above code won't even compile.

Comment: Sean, its formatted now. Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a [filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html) and enable it before accessing the collection.